# Firebug won't break on breakpoint in startup JavaScript except in first script element

Tags: javascript, firebug, startup, breakpoints

I can't get Firebug to stop on breakpoints that I set on JS within a <script> tag; i.e. JS that runs when the page is loaded.
*unless* the <script> is the 1st such tag on the page.

In the example below there are 3 script blocks.  When this is loaded into the browser, I can set breakpoints on any of the executable lines in any block.  However, execution will only stop on breadkpoints in the 1st script block.

Line numbers are green in the 1st block and grey in the others.  Also, in the tab that displays the list of breakpoints, the breakpoint in the 1st script is labeled with the file name next to the enable/disable checkbox; The other breakpoints are labeled "undefined"

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
   <head>  
      <script type="text/javascript" >  
         var j = 4;  
         j=5;  
      </script>  
      <script type="text/javascript" >  
         j=137;  
      </script>  
   </head>  
   <body>  
      <script type="text/javascript" >  
         document.write( "j=" + j );  
      </script>  
   </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: are you certain that the points you are setting are portions of code actually being invoked? It could be that the breakpoints are never reached because a condition was not met to process that segment

Comment: You'll need to show us a pared-down test case to help further.

Comment: yes. the code I want to break on is being run; if I change it, the changes appear in the web page.

Comment: check if this piece of javascript is being included from an external js file, is it being included twice ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and like you I was trying to figure out why firebug have this, imho, strange behavior. Actually I think it is a bug. But I also found a workaround that I hope could help.

You only need to wrap your code within an anonymous functions, then you can add again breakpoints.

[image: Firebug breakpoints within anonymous functions]